# Error (“EXC_BAD_ACCESS”) while trying to open(create) SQLite d/b

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Here's the code... anybody see what's wrong?  Also, why does the 2nd NSLog of "errmsg" cause the debugger to crash when debugging to the device (iPhone 3GS)

```
    // Get the path to the database file
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ppcipher.s3db"];
const char *cDatabasePath = [databasePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"databasePath: %@", databasePath);

    NSString *sqlCommand = @"CREATE TABLE CardData (card_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, card_name TEXT NOT NULL, "
        @"card_type TEXT, cide_val TEXT, create_date TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, user_notes TEXT, gps_loc TEXT)"; 
    const char cSQLCommand = [sqlCommand cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    char * errmsg = NULL;   

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:databasePath error:NULL];  //  <------------  delete d/b  TESTING ONLY! 

    BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if(!fileExists)  {
        if(sqlite3_open(cDatabasePath, db) == SQLITE_OK) { // doesn't exist, so create it...
            sqlite3_exec(db, &cSQLCommand, NULL, NULL, &errmsg);  //  now create the table...
            NSLog(@"error: %@", errmsg);
        }
```

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API directly in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (a SQLite wrapper) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) (an object graph manager) instead.

Comment: I respect your opinion... however, I have chosen to use the API directly, mostly to learn... can you tell me why I'm getting the sqlite3_open error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's crashing because `errmsg` is not an Objective-C object, which you're requiring by your use of the `%@` substitution.  `errmsg` is a `char *`, which means you should be using `%s`.

As for why it's crashing....

`sqlite3_open` is defined as:

```
int sqlite3_open(
  const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
  sqlite3 **ppDb          /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
);
```

Your `db` is declared as `sqlite3*`.  In other words, you're passing the wrong thing in.  You should be doing:

```
sqlite3_open(cDatabasePath, &db)
```

While your desire to understand the SQLite C API is great, I still think you should use FMDB.  It really mitigates these sorts of errors and lets you concentrate on the real problems with your code.

Comment: I hate Objective-C!  It makes no sense what-so-ever to .NET programmers like myself!  I'm trying to learn it, but as you can see, it's a real struggle for me... thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.  I'll have another request for help in a few minutes :D